# Allow multiple provider states with parameters ( Golang )

Tags: go, pact

As our team ( namely myself and two other developers ) spiked on PACT past week or so, one of the areas of concern is not having the ability associate parameters to provider states.   The absence of this key feature ( which is slated for version 3 release ), we likely will not get buy in from each of our respective service sub-teams.

@MattFellows -  Any projections on when version 3 might be available for Go?  Any chance we can get this feature earlier?

**Allow multiple provider states with parameters
In previous versions, provider states are defined as a descriptive string. There is no way to infer the data required for the state without encoding the values into the description.**

```
{
  "providerState": "an alligator with the given name Mary exists and the user Fred is logged in"
}
The change would be:

{
  "providerStates": [
    {
      "name": "an alligator with the given name exists",
      "params": {"name" : "Mary"}
    }, {
      "name": "the user is logged in",
      "params" : { "username" : "Fred"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that it won't be available until version 3.

You can still achieve what you are after, however. The state itself is just a handle for the *Consumer* to some set of data on the *Provider* - that can be a one-to-one or one-to-many mapping - it's completely up to you.

Typically the *Provider* is notified of the state during verification, it will then setup a test data fixture (often seeding a database) that sets up the 'state' of the entire system based on that reference, which allows the *Consumer* test to run.

Whilst the ability to pass through parameters and multiple states is nice, it's somewhat an advanced feature and I very much doubt this will be the first problem you run into as a team. I've never needed to use them myself.

For a crude but effective example of this, take a look at the [gin](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-go/blob/master/examples/gin/provider/user_service_test.go#L47-L59) code in the [examples](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-go/tree/master/examples) folder of the project.

Comment: Hey Matthew, 

Thanks for sending over the example, always helps when communicating.  We are currently following that exact pattern in our spike.

We will have a common use case where by there will be multiple states for a test.  This will not be a one off edge case, but definitely pervasive enough that we've given it thought about what could help in writing and maintaining our tests. 

In addition, the ability to mix and match params for a given state is simplified with this feature.